# ImportError: No module named 'fig_code'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.5

I am using ipython notebook. I am using python 3.5 . I got No module named 'fig_code' error while running a program as written below.

```
#Code
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform')

knn.fit(X, y)

X_pred = [3, 5, 4, 2]
result = knn.predict([X_pred, ])

print(iris.target_names[result])

print(iris.target_names)

print(knn.predict_proba([X_pred, ]))

from fig_code import plot_iris_knn
plot_iris_knn()
```

## The error I am getting is as follows

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e8dd8ed3c9cb> in <module>()
     18 print(knn.predict_proba([X_pred, ]))
     19 
---> 20 from fig_code import plot_iris_knn
     21 plot_iris_knn()

ImportError: No module named 'fig_code'
```

I tried to install fig_code by using 'pip install fig_code' but I am getting this error

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fig_code (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for fig_code"
```

I have searched the error to resolve this issue but no use.
Can anyone help me resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are following 'fig_code' from Jake Vanderplas lecture from pyon2015 on sklearn.
Okay, coming straightway to your problem. go to the https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_pycon2015 and download/cloan it. In 'notebooks' you will find fig_code folder. save it in the folder where your script is ....Now you will able to call 'fig_code'....

Answer (score 1):

`fig_code` refers to a folder supplementary to Jake VanderPlas's sklearn ipython notebooks.

1. Download the `fig_code` module from Github by typing the following command in Terminal:

`svn checkout https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_pycon2015/trunk/notebooks/fig_code`

A folder named 'fig_code' will appear in your home directory.

2. Move 'fig_code' to the folder where your script is.

Comment: Use `svn checkout https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_pycon2015` to download the whole project